# Merging Arrays recursively into a Single Dimensional Array

Tags: php, recursion

I'm having trouble figuring out how to merge arrays recursively into one single dimensional array. Here's an example:

```
    $array = [
        'one' => [
            'two' => [
                'three' => [],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $array2 = [
        'four' => [
            'five' => [
                'six' => [
                    'seven' => [],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Expected output:

```
$array = [
     'one',
     'two',
     'three',
     'four',
     'five',
     'six',
     'seven',
];
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to be able to accomplish the expected? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `array_walk_recursive()` and grab all keys into an array

Comment: Are you able to show an example? I'm not exactly sure how to  retrieve the expected output with `array_walk_recursive()`...

Comment: When you use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) with an anonymous function you can pass a result array [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) with the keyword [use](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and fill it up with iterating through each key.

Comment: Using `array_walk_recursive()` won't work: `Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function.` So essentially it'll read my arrays as empty

Comment: @SteveBauman, [there is a way around it](https://gist.github.com/kohnmd/11197713)

Comment: @MrOffice OP is right here, since he wants the key `array_walk_recursive()` won't work for him here in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a [solution](http://codeaid.net/php/extract-all-keys-from-a-multidimensional-array), as you might have expected. You just have to adapt it slightly for your several arrays:

```
// To flatten an array using keys as values.
function array_keys_multi(array $array) {
    $keys = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $keys[] = $key;
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys_multi($value));
        }
    }
    return $keys;
}

// To merge the flattened arrays.
function array_merge_multi() {
    $result = array();
    foreach (func_get_args() as $array) {
        $result = array_merge($result, array_keys_multi($array));
    }
    return $result;
}

$result = array_merge_multi($array, $array2);
```

You can use any number of arguments in `array_merge_multi()`, just like in `array_merge()`.

Tested here: https://eval.in/522491